# Placeholders in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know there are placeholders for [selects](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html) in jQuery Mobile.

```html
<select id="salutation" data-native-menu="false">
  <option id="salPlac" data-placeholder="true" value="">Salutation</option>
  <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
  <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
</select>
```

But are there similar placeholders for textareas and inputs when using jQuery Mobile?

Like this: (doesnt work)

```html
 <textarea type="input" class="regular" id="textBox" data-placeholder="true">Type in here</textarea>
```

I know they are available in HTML5, but I want to use jQuery Mobile if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/#Placeholder `placeholder="foo"` not `data-placeholder="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute called "data-placeholder" available for text box and text area in jquery mobile. So you need to use the HTML5 placeholder attribute suggested by Omar.

Here is the link http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/#ui-page-top